# Adding buttons inside UISearchBar

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

[image]

I want to add a button (bar) inside a UISearchbar and another one just outside the UISearchbar as shown in the image. Any help on this appreciated.

Thanks in advance
Naveen

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### Edit :

As stated by @NicolasMiari in the comments :

> This no longer works post-iOS 7, since the bookmarks button is rendered inside the bar's input text field.

---

For the button inside the search bar, you can use the bookmark button and change its image. You simply go to your storyboard (if you use one), select the search bar, and activate the option "Shows Bookmarks Button". Then, in your code, set the image you want :

```
[_searchBar setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"My-Custom-Image"] forSearchBarIcon:UISearchBarIconBookmark state:UIControlStateNormal];
```

You can detect a click on this button with the following delegate method :

```
- (void)searchBarBookmarkButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {

    NSLog(@"click");
}
```

Comment: This no longer works post-iOS 7, since the bookmarks button is rendered **inside** the bar's input text field.

Comment: This is working in iOS 10 and 11. See Swift 4 oneliner from Strat Aguilar: `searchBar.setImage(UIImage(named: "myImage"), for: UISearchBarIcon.bookmark, state: .normal)`

Answer (score 23):

Swift 4

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

   var searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      searchController.delegate = self 
      searchController.searchBar.delegate = self 
      searchController.searchBar.showsBookmarkButton = true
      searchController.searchBar.setImage(UIImage(named: "myImage"), for: .bookmark, state: .normal)
   }

}

extension ViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {

   func searchBarBookmarkButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
      print("click")
   }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

The fastest way to add a button in UISearchBar is to update the bookmark button like this:

```
[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"customImage.png"] forSearchBarIcon:UISearchBarIconBookmark state:UIControlStateNormal];
```

If you need to adjust the offset,

```
[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar setPositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(-10, 0) forSearchBarIcon:UISearchBarIconBookmark];
```

Don't forget to activate the option "Shows Bookmarks Button" in story board.